# How does my internet look over a public wifi connection?

Tags: wifi, vpn

I am curious.  I use VPN over a public wifi.  How does my internet traffic look as it is being transmitted over the public wifi connection?  Can anyone intercept and determine what websites I visit?

The VPN I use uses a virtual network adapter and I force using the VPN's DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

If everything with the VPN is working correctly, nobody can see what you are browsing. The most that they can tell is that you've created a VPN connection to your VPN provider.